How to show the integral of a normal-pointing vector over a closed surface vanishes?
The divergence theorem in $4$ dimensions says $$\int_R {A^\mu}_{,\mu}\,d^4x = \int_{\partial R} A^\mu \hat{n}_\mu d^3x$$ where $\hat{n}_\mu$ is the 'outward pointing unit-normal vector' at each point of the boundary $\partial R$. Here I am using the notation $S_{,\mu}=\partial S/\partial x^\mu$. (Also, $A^\mu$ is a contravariant vector and $\hat{n}_\mu$ is a covariant vector, but that doesn't matter.)
One can give a specific formulation of $\hat{n}_\mu$ if desired. As a $3$-D surface in $4$-D space, $\partial R$ can be defined implicitly by $F(x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3 )=0$ for some scalar function $F$. A normal vector to this surface is $n=∇F=(F_{,0},F_{,1},F_{,2},F_{,3})$, or $n_μ=F_{,μ}$. The unit normal is then $\hat{n}_\mu = F_{,\mu}(g^{\rho\sigma} F_{,\rho}F_{,\sigma})^{-1/2}$.
The case I have is where $A^\mu$ is constant on the boundary $\partial R$. Therefore,
$$\int_R {A^\mu}_{,\mu}\,d^4x = \int_{\partial R} A^\mu \hat{n}_\mu d^3x = A^\mu\int_{\partial R}\hat{n}_\mu d^3x.$$
If this were three dimensions, it would look like (for $R$ some arbitrary region of space):
$$\int_R \text{div}\textbf{A}\,d^4x = \textbf{A}\bullet \int_{\partial R}\hat{\textbf{n}} \,d^3x.$$
In three dimensions it's easy to show $\int\hat{\textbf{n}} \,d^3x=0$ by writing $\hat{n}_k = \hat{\textbf{x}}_k \cdot\textbf{n}$ and using the divergence theorem backward, since $\text{div}(\hat{\textbf{x}}_k)=0$.
My question is: how to show that $\int_{\partial R}\hat{n}_\mu d^3x$ vanishes in the four (or $n$) dimensional case?

Maybe I have it ... If $A^\mu$ is constant on $\partial R$, then $$\int_R A^\mu_{,\mu}, d^4 x =  \int_{\partial R} A^\mu \hat{n}\mu ,d^3 x =A^\mu \int{\partial R} \hat{n}_\mu ,d^3 x.$$
But by the divergence theorem again
$$\int_{\partial R} \hat{n}\mu ,d^3 x = \int{\partial R} \delta^\sigma_\mu \hat{n}\sigma ,d^3x =  \int{R} \delta^\sigma_{\mu,\sigma}, d^4x =0.$$ Is that it?

That will work. Intuitively when integrating the unit normal vector to a closed "surface", you would expect the vectors on opposite sides of the surface to cancel out. The divergence theorem argument turns that intuitive concept into a mathematical one.
